# For Spring Boot 1.2.3, how to set ignore null value in JSON serialization?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, serialization, null, jackson

In the Spring Boot 1.2.3, we can customize the Jackson ObjectMapper via properties file. But I didn't find a attribute can set Jackson ignore null value when serialization the Object to JSON string.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.*= # see Jackson's DeserializationFeature
spring.jackson.generator.*= # see Jackson's JsonGenerator.Feature
spring.jackson.mapper.*= # see Jackson's MapperFeature
spring.jackson.parser.*= # see Jackson's JsonParser.Feature
spring.jackson.serialization.*=
```

I want to archive the same code like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was an enhancement for Spring Boot 1.3.0.

- [Support for spring.jackson.include](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2532)
- [Add properties for Jackson serializationInclusion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2634)

So unfortunately you'll need to configure it programmatically on 1.2.3

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Shop {
    //...
}
```

Comment: it says Inclusion is deprecated

Comment: This inclusion is deprecated. Instead @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 needs to be used as stated in the below answer

Answer (score 71):

Add the following line to your `application.properties` file.

> spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null

For versions of Jackson prior to 2.7:

> spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non_null

Comment: this only available for Spring Boot version 1.3.0

Comment: remember not to use 
    new RestTemplate()
 because it would not use this config,but create default converters. 
    RestTemplateBuilder.build()
 uses all configs

Comment: @cjungel, I have tried this solution but not working for me, I am using 1.5.7 version of spring boot

Comment: I am using `1.5.10.RELEASE` version and it worked like charm for me.

Comment: Check the complete list in: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Answer (score 24):

This was a good solution before deprecation: 
`@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

But now you should use:

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ClassName { 
...`

You can take a look here:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html

Comment: Looks like the enum com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Inclusion was deprecated in ver 2.6 of jackson-databind

Answer (score 17):

For Spring Boot 1.4.x, you can include the following line to your *application.properties*

`spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null`

Answer (score 11):

Class-wide,

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyModel { .... }
```

Property-wide:

```
public class MyModel {   
    .....

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private String myProperty;

    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder) {
    return mapperBuilder.build().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
  }
```

that works for me

Comment: This was the right solution for me, as I didn't want to add annotations to my shared object classes