# The spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion environment setting does not seem to be working

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot introduced a new feature in 1.3 to define what properties are included by Jackson during serialization. This feature was pointed out in question [For Spring Boot 1.2.3, how to set ignore null value in JSON serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042507/for-spring-boot-1-2-3-how-to-set-ignore-null-value-in-json-serialization). However it does not seem to be working for me. I'm using Spring-Boot version 1.3.0.M5. Is there any other configuration that needs to be done besides adding that property to my application.properties file?

I dug into the issue a bit and can see where the property is actually picked up by the JacksonAutoConfiguration object when my Spring Boot based application is loaded. From what I can tell it does not seem the message converters(i.e. MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter), or the factories that build them, use this builder to set the ObjectMapper. Therefore the ObjectMapper used has its _serializationConfig._serializationInclusion property set to null( and not NON_NULL in my case).

It seems like this might be a bug, but wanted to verify I'm not missing something before submitting an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by extending RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration. One of our application configuration classes was extended to configure the RepositoryRestConfiguration using the configureRepositoryRestConfiguration method. This was done so that our entity ids get serialized.(We aren't ready to move to HATEOAS). Changing that class to extend RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter instead fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem when use spring-boot 2.0.3 with kotlin. The root cause is that when spring boot init default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` it does'n use the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` instance which is created by `JacksonAutoConfiguration`. So you can just provide a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` by yourself and use the auto-configured `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. Code:

```java

```
@Autowired
lateinit var jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder

@Bean
fun mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(): MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    var mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.objectMapper = jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build()
    return mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
}
```

```