# Same controller returning different amounts of information depending on role in Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my REST server, I have a controller with the mapping "/users":

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<UserModel> getAllUsers() {...}
```

I would like to use Spring Boot Security with Roles to determine how much information to return. For example:

```
public class UserModel {
  private MetaDataModel user_metadata;
  private MetaDataModel private_admin_metadata; 
}
```

So that when getAllUsers is called by a user with the admin role, the UserModel supplies both fields, otherwise it only supplies the user_metadata field. I'm completely open to the idea that there is a better approach to this so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: There are a lot of solutions. Maybe you should use Google and find some of the solutions to make your question not so broad.

Answer (score 0):

Set appropriate property of response DTO. And use include not null json annotation. Refer [For Spring Boot 1.2.3, how to set ignore null value in JSON serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042507/for-spring-boot-1-2-3-how-to-set-ignore-null-value-in-json-serialization)