# How to hide unpassed fields of Json request from log

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Example I have entity orders.

As a request I am expecting only `order num` and quantity from orders class.

I see in log as:

```
{
Order ID : null,
Order num : 'O0001',
Qty : '20',
Optional : null
LastUpdated : null
}
```

Since only `order num` and `Qty` was entered by user, I want to hide other non passed values in log.

Please suggest how can that be made.

Comment: How are you logging that object that you get JSON as the result?

Comment: Could you try with @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For Spring Boot 1.2.3, how to set ignore null value in JSON serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042507/for-spring-boot-1-2-3-how-to-set-ignore-null-value-in-json-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below Annotation to your Entity class.This would hide the null values.

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  
    public class Order{
```